# Is it sensible to upvote a question that claims to have issues with Ubuntu but provides logs from another distro?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing low quality posts I stumbled across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884615/system-is-booting-only-occasionally) in which the OP describes intermittent problems booting with 3 versions of Ubuntu but is now booting KDE Neon. The question while well described, provides logs from KDE Neon running kernel 4.9.10 My gut reaction is that this is off topic either due to the distro currently in use or due to the fact that the problem exists across several versions and distributions and either way would likely be better served on [U&L.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) I'm curious as to what logic chain leads one to believe that this question is both on topic and worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While establishing that the post is off-topic, and most definitely after finding out that it is off-topic, I would refrain from upvoting it, since questions with upvotes don't get deleted by the system, unless people with >10k find and delete them, even if they are closed, and we don't want off-topic stuff cluttering up the site and misleading people.

Comment: Agreed. I guess people sometimes upvote any question they don't know the answer to. I'm sure I was guilty of that early on...

Comment: I disagree, upvote any good question just to encourage the asker. Does not matter what the effect on automatically triggered actions is. People > machines.

Comment: @don.joey what machines are prioritised here? I'm thinking about the interests of current users and future visitors of the site.

Comment: Fair enough. Good point. In that case current user > future user.

Comment: @don.joey many users > one user ?

Comment: You have not data to claim that this is for one user only.

Comment: @don.joey I mean, the person who gets an upvote is the only person who feels encouraged by that upvote I think?

Comment: also @don.joey I wasn't opposing the interests of current and future users, I was saying both current and future benefit if the site is on-topic

Comment: Honestly, we don't upvote enough so we should not build new rules about when we should not upvote. Encourage people to ask and participate, don't be purist. Anyway, that's my take.

Comment: @don.joey well at least I can definitely agree with you we should be upvoting more (just not on off-topic questions!) Thanks for engaging :)

Answer (score 11):

The first thing to do is to ask whether they are truly on Ubuntu or not.  Then go from there.

It is entirely possible for someone to custom-run the higher kernel and software on Ubuntu by compiling and doing it themselves.

If they say "No, I'm not, I'm actually on XYZ", then you know it's offtopic.  Then we can truly act on it.

I've asked them in comments to clarify what OS they're on.  We can move from there once we get a reply.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess people sometimes upvote any question they don't know the answer to. I'm sure I was guilty of that early on...